# How do I set system proxy on OS (Windows)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm designing a VPN for windows and I want to set proxy on the system,

There are several ways to do this (e.g. from registry or command line), but I'm looking for a better solution (like a package or something)

Are there any better solution(s) to set proxy on OS in an electron desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

For bash and sh users, add the export line given above into a new file called /etc/profile.d/http_proxy.sh file:
copy

```
echo "export http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:3128/" > /etc/profile.d/http_proxy.sh
```

For csh and tcsh users, use the following command to set the http_proxy variable in a new file called /etc/profile.d/http_proxy.csh file:
copy

```
echo "setenv http_proxy http://proxy.example.com:3128/" > /etc/profile.d/http_proxy.csh
```

The extension of these files determines which shell will read them. The commands are not interchangeable.

When the username or password uses the @ symbol, add a backslash () before the @ - for example:

```
export http_proxy=http://DOMAIN\\USERN\@ME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT
```

For windows,

```
setx http_proxy http://user:password@proxyIP:proxyPort/
```

Comment: Can you explain how do I implement your solution on windows ?

Comment: It is there at the end of the answer.. you have to handle it os specific.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I have to execute it with command line which I prefer not to.

Comment: you can create a shell script, PowerShell script. and execute it after checking the os type 

check the os type 
according to execute the code. so your application will be os indepent